# Cordova Open Link In New Window InAppBrowser

Tags: ios, cordova

I am trying to use the InAppBrowser to open an external webpage, and that works fine!
The page opens up in the app, and I can open up multiple tabs as well.

But there is one problem. When I open a webpage (remote site), it has it's own external links.
When I click on those links, it opens them in the same InAppBrowser tab in the app.

I don't want that behavior. I want to be able to send ALL those links to the ios safari system browser.
I am having the hardest time getting links to open outside of the app I'm writing in Cordova/PhoneGap.

I am using the InAppBrowser plugin and I want every single link in the entire app to open outside.

Here is the code in the plugin that opens links:

```
    - (void)open:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
CDVPluginResult* pluginResult;

NSString* url = [command argumentAtIndex:0];
NSString* target = [command argumentAtIndex:1 withDefault:kInAppBrowserTargetSelf];
NSString* options = [command argumentAtIndex:2 withDefault:@"" andClass:[NSString class]];

self.callbackId = command.callbackId;

if (url != nil) {
    NSURL* baseUrl = [self.webView.request URL];
    NSURL* absoluteUrl = [[NSURL URLWithString:url relativeToURL:baseUrl] absoluteURL];

    if ([self isSystemUrl:absoluteUrl]) {
        target = kInAppBrowserTargetSystem;
    }

    if ([target isEqualToString:kInAppBrowserTargetSelf]) {
        [self openInCordovaWebView:absoluteUrl withOptions:options];
    } else if ([target isEqualToString:kInAppBrowserTargetSystem]) {
        [self openInSystem:absoluteUrl];
    } else { // _blank or anything else
        [self openInInAppBrowser:absoluteUrl withOptions:options];
    }
```

Now, I've tried changing this in so many different ways to make it open outside, and it doesn't work!!
When I use window.open, it should obviously open a new tab in the app, but ANY link going ANYWHERE from the opened pages should open outside the app and in the system browser.

Some of the pages opened using window.open are remote http pages, and for the weirdest reason I cannot get those links in the reomote page to open outside.

Is there away to change that code up top to force it to open those links outside?

The Funny thing Is that I can do it in the regular cordova browser if I open one of the classes:

platforms/ios/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVWebViewDelegate.m LINE 207

```
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked){ 

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:request.URL];
        return NO;
    } 

    return YES;
```

So please tell me what my options are.